# Remove underscore tags from big .txt file in python

Tags: python, split

I have a big .txt file (around 600 mb) and I am trying to split all underscores and its leading text

```
xxxxxxxx_NUM 0.20825405 -0.0756654 0.026837101
have_VERB -0.24344832 0.2747727 -0.024150277
two_NUM -0.038767103 0.20430847 0.10068103
```

I've tried using the split method and regex pattern but didn't succeed.
As an example, the output of this text should be:

```
xxxxxxxx 0.20825405 -0.0756654 0.026837101
have -0.24344832 0.2747727 -0.024150277
two -0.038767103 0.20430847 0.10068103
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) module with regex replacement:

```
import fileinput
import re

with fileinput.input(files='your_filename.txt',
                     encoding='utf-8', inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = re.sub(r'_[^_\s]+', '', line, count=1)
        print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to write the content to a different file, this worked out for me:with open('data.txt', 'w') as f_to_write:
    with open("filepath\model.txt",
              encoding='utf-8') as f_to_read:
        for line in f_to_read:
            line=re.sub(r'_[^_\s]+', '', line, count=1)
            f_to_write.write(line)